# ServiceStack Http Util - GetJsonFromUrlAsync terminates program abruptly

Tags: http, .net-core, servicestack-text

Using the ServiceStack Http Util extension methods, and following the exact instructions [found here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Http-Utils), invoking:

```
var result = await uri.GetJsonFromUrlAsync();
```

My application just terminates - no exception, no result, nothing. If I switch the call from async to sync it works just fine.

This is the only thing in the output windows:

```
The program '[42260] dotnet.exe: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[42260] dotnet.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Any hints here or additional troubleshooting steps?

Comment: What URL were you using or how can we repro this?

Comment: @mythz - Well, I created a quick netcoreapp console app to paste a gist and it worked fine. So I then created a quick xUnit test project and it worked just fine. That leaves: it's my problem... Thank you for responding.